# MySQL INNER JOIN with date as condition

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to use inner join to get the data from two tables using date as one of the condition.
 But since the second table contain dateTime column type, I want to use only the date to check for condition.
 When i run the code using Postman, it says I have **`error in SQL syntax at line (DATE)checkInDateTime = $rideDate`** .
 I also have test the SQL without taking the date into condition and the SQL works .
 Is there any ways to use the date as condition in InnerJoin method? Please help me . 
Thanks.
 
P/s : my dateTime column store values such as **`2015-01-08 11:18:02`**

```
//get all rides from table rides
$result = mysql_query("SELECT first.ID, first.fullname, 
second.checkInDateTime FROM first INNER JOIN second ON first.ID = 
second.riderID WHERE second.ridesID = $rideID AND second.
CAST(checkInDateTime AS DATE) = $rideDate") or die(mysql_error());


//check for empty result
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    //loop all result and put into array riders
    $response["riders"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        //temp array
        $rider = array();
        $rider["riderID"] = $row["ID"];
        $rider["riderName"] = $row["fullname"];
        $rider["timeCheckedIn"] = $row["checkInDateTime"];

        //push single ride into final response array
        array_push($response["riders"], $rider);
    }
    //success
    $response["success"] = 1;

    //print JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    //no rides found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No riders found";

    //print JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Comment: Are sure your date column name is (DATE)checkInDateTime

Comment: 1) you should really use mysqli or pdo (mysql is deprecated) 2) What does $rideDate look like (example pls)?

Comment: I'm guessing the `(DATE)checkInDateTime` is an attempt at typecasting, and you're getting the sql error because that's not the right syntax... try `CAST(checkInDateTime AS DATE)` instead.

Comment: @JoelCox Is absolutely correct. The better question is why are you naming your columns by date time ... ?

Comment: @ Joe T : $rideDate = 2015-01-08

Comment: I see. Ok I will try to use CAST

Comment: @ Ohgodwhy: The data is stored in dateTime column for when a record is create, the database will capture the current time and date. Now I want to retrieve the records according to the ridesID and rideDate which the rideDate is containing date only.

Comment: @JoelCox I hv tried CAST but still got error. Please refer to the edited SQL in  my question. Is the CAST I put in correct?

Comment: Yep, that looks right. Could you please echo out the sql query instead of passing it to mysql_query, and post that for us to see? This will help us see the final value after all variables are inserted in there.

Comment: Run this: `echo "SELECT first.ID, first.fullname, 
second.checkInDateTime FROM first INNER JOIN second ON first.ID = 
second.riderID WHERE second.ridesID = $rideID AND second.
CAST(checkInDateTime AS DATE) = $rideDate";` And tell us what it says. Just as a way for us to see the final query after variables have been replaced with their actual values.

Comment: @JoelCox Sorry.. I think it's my fault. I forgot to put single quote at $rideDate in sql statement. Your CAST did works! Thanks so much. And can you post your CAST answer because I want to mark it as answer. Thanks

Comment: Ah cool that makes sense (it's exactly the sort of thing I would've been looking for with the result of that echo). Glad you sorted it out.

Comment: @JoelCox can you post your CAST answer because I want to mark it as answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the `(DATE)checkInDateTime` is an attempt at typecasting, and you're getting the sql error because that's not the right syntax... try `CAST(checkInDateTime AS DATE)` instead.